# How to create an open cover from a finite open family and it is closed reduction?

Tags: general-topology

In our lecture notes we have the following remark:

Let $U=\{u_1,…,u_k\}$ be a finite open family and $F=\{F_1,…,F_k\}$ be a closed reduction of $U$.

Then $H=\{H_1,…,H_k\}$ such that $H_i=u_i$ or $H_i=F_i^c$ is a finite open cover of $X,∀i=1,…,k$.

How is this a cover of $X$? What does $H_i=u_i$ or $H_i=F_i^c$ mean?

Comment: What is the meaning of a reduction?

Comment: @Elma, $F_i\subseteq u_i,\forall i=1,...,k$

Comment: I think the statement is unclear, for instance take $U=\{ B(0,1) \}$ to be the collection whose unique element is the open unit ball on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $F=\{ \overline{B}(0,1/2)\}$. No matter how you choose $H_1$ to be, you cannot cover $\mathbb{R}^2$. I think the statement must say that you can make a cover consisting entirely of $u_i$'s and $F_i^c $'s.